# Is there a quick way to delete Foldered bookmarks directly from Safari bookmark bar?

Tags: safari, bookmarks

I like to group my bookmarks into Folders in the Bookmark Bar.

But I cannot find an easy way to delete these bookmarks!

The only way I know to do this is to go to **Show All Bookmarks**, then browse down to the shortcut and select it and delete it - this totally gets in the way of workflow.

Is there any way to delete a **Foldered** bookmark **from the bookmark bar**?!

NB - I am not talking about standalone bookmarks, deleting those is easy and intuitive.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Foldered bookmarks are presented as options of a contextual menu (think about a folder in a file manager and the contextual menu you get when right clicking on it), so either left or right click executes/opens the bookmarks (drags are nulled out and equal a click). You can see the same behavior in other apps which have some sort of Bookmarks Bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a folder, hold down the Command and Option keys, then drag the folder off the Bookmarks Bar. You'll get a confirmation dialog saying "Are you sure?" Just click the Delete Folder button in the dialog.

Holding the Command and Control keys keys down gets you a contextual menu that allows you to edit the name of the folder, edit its contents (jumps you to the Bookmarks window to do that), delete it, copy it, and a few other things.

Comment: This is helpful - and a command I didn't know, and certainly speeds up the workflow. But - is there an even better way - I want to delete items within the folder, not the whole folder. (Best answer so far though!) :-)

Comment: Also, just noticed that right clicking the folder gives you the same menu.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Open-Book-Icon](http://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=6501) probably is the easiest way to delete Safari folded bookmark

Comment: Hi Serith - sorry, my question was badly worded - I've amended it now. I am looking to delete bookmarks within folders in the bookmarks bar - any ideas?

Comment: Your suggestions only work for non-Foldered bookmarks...

Answer (score 0):

We're talking about the Bookmarks Bar in Safari, right?

Hold down the Command key and drag it off—poof, disappears.

Same thing with Finder toolbar (plus you can add anything you like to Finder Toolbar by holding down Command key while you drag it into place.)

Comment: Sorry - I am talking about bookmarks within **folders** in the bookmarks bar. Command Drag just opens the bookmark in a new tab!

Answer (score 0):

Hit <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. It will open a bookmark editor; it's very easy to delete anything within a folder from there.

Answer (score -4):

Just delete the whole safari folder in the library directory

Comment: Elephant gun / House fly? The OP wanted to delete one bookmark, quickly, not the whole lot, slowly.